# How to remove the 'Tax/VAT Number' line from Magento 2 check-out?

Tags: taxvat

```
Magento 2.4.2-p1
Smartwave Porto
13 Amasty extensions
```

---

I have done a composer update and updated my Amasty extensions yesterday and ever since then, an extra line appeared in my checkout.

It is labeled:

**Tax/VAT Number**

We never had this before and **we can not have that**. I've googled this and checked Magento default settings in:

"Stores -> Configuration -> Customer Configuration -> Show VAT Number at Frontend"

and **all setting having to do with VAT are set to "No".**

I'm not sure if this is in any way related to the Amasty One Step Checkout? (we have that extension disabled)

I've looked everywhere in Amasty's extensions including:

Stores -> Configuration -> AMASTY EXTENSIONS -> ONE STEP CHECKOUT PRO -> ONE STEP CHECKOUT

*but there doesn't appear to be anything relevant there.*

Is this part of the Magento core functionality? And if so, why did it just appear by itself after doing the updates (I didn't update the version of Magento, just the composer and probably some or all of Amasty's extensions).

***How does one remove this line from the checkout?***

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In file `app/code/Vendor/Checkout/Plugin/ModifyCheckoutField.php` which I shared with you on [In-line translations do not update on the front end!](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/361508/in-line-translations-do-not-update-on-the-front-end/361577#361577)

- Replace `$shippingAddressFieldset['vat_id']['label'] = __('Recipient\'s Tax/VAT Number');`
  with
  `$shippingAddressFieldset['vat_id']['config']['componentDisabled'] = true;`
- Replace `$billingFormFields['vat_id']['label'] = __('Your Tax/VAT Number');`
  with
  `$billingFormFields['vat_id']['config']['componentDisabled'] = true;`

Comment: I have implemented this and it works. Thank you Tu Van!